# CSS issue: Javascript password validation message placing error

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using [this link for password match validation](http://www.keithscode.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorials/a-simple-javascript-password-validator.html).
All is working very fine. But the problem is that I am getting message on top of the fields, not beside the confirm password field. Here what I tried;

**JavaScript Function**

```
function checkPass(){
    var password = document.getElementById('password');
    var password2 = document.getElementById('password2');             
    var message = document.getElementById('confirmMessage');
    var goodColor = "#66cc66";
    var badColor = "#ff6666";
                  
    if(password.value == password2.value){
        password2.style.backgroundColor = goodColor;
        message.style.color = goodColor;
        message.innerHTML = 'Passwords Match!'            
    }else{
        //The passwords do not match.
        //Set the color to the bad color and
        //notify the user.
        password2.style.backgroundColor = badColor;
        message.style.color = badColor;
        message.innerHTML = 'Passwords Do Not Match!'
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <form name="form" id="form" class="form" onsubmit="someFunction(this);return false">
        <label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" style="color: #B8B894;" value="Password" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value='Password'}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Password') {this.value=''}" name="password" id="password" />
        <label for="password2">Confirm Pass:</label><input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" onkeyup="checkPass(); return false;" />
        <span id="confirmMessage" class="confirmMessage"></span><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
        <input type="button" name="reset_form" value="Reset All Fields " onclick="this.form.reset();">
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
  #wrapper {width:75%; margin:70px auto}
  .form {float:left; padding:0 139px 10px 10px; background:#f3f3f3; border:2px solid #cfcfcf width: 100%;}
  .form label {float:left; width:100px; padding:10px 10px 0 0; font-weight:bold font:12px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#666}
  .form select {float:left; width:146px; margin-top:10px}
  .form input {float:left; margin-top:10px}
  .form .submit {clear:both}
  .form #confirmMessage {font-size: 0.9em; margin:5px; padding:10px 10px;}
  .form input.password {font:normal normal normal 1em verdana,arial,sans-serif; padding:4px 6px 3px 6px; border:1px solid #ccc; border-top-color:#aaa; border-bottom-color:#ddd; cursor:text; width:286px; -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);}
  #msg {display:none; position:absolute; z-index:200; background:url(images/msg_arrow.gif) left center no-repeat; padding-left:7px}
  #msgcontent {display:block; background:#f3e6e6; border:3px solid #924949; border-left:none; padding:5px; min-width:150px; max-width:250px}
</style>
```

The result is renders like below image;
[image]

How this can be solved?

**EDIT :** I forget to put in my question #wrapper in CSS. I added now in my question.

**EDIT # 2 :** Now I put everything between my `<style>` tag. Kindly help.

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't match the result when I try this; there must be more CSS involved. And you have a typo in your css (you're missing an `#`) but that doesn't help solve the issue.

Comment: With the extra CSS, the result here still doesn't look anything like your screenshot. It looks like [this](http://i5.photobucket.com/albums/y170/Mr_Lister/passmatch.png). Can you disable your stylesheet and see what your page looks like then?

Comment: There are definitely more styles involved, a `label` does not display like that by itself, you need to show all styles involved.

Comment: I created a fiddle that shows this working. What browser are you testing in? Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/hnTUa/

Comment: @AlexMorales I am using Firefox 11.0

Comment: Did you take a look at the fiddle?

Comment: @AlexMorales Sorry for late reply. As for your fiddle, its not working for me. I mean it give me same results as I am having before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're floating everything to the left now, so the span doesn't know where it should go.
If you'd used the code from the page you said you got the code from, this wouldn't have happened.

Anyway, I removed some of the floats and a couple of the errors you had in your css, and it now looks like this.

```
 #wrapper {width:75%; margin:70px auto}
 .form {padding:0 10px 10px 10px; background:#f3f3f3; border:2px solid #cfcfcf;}
 .form label {display:inline-block; width:100px; margin:10px 0;
    font:bold 12px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#666}
 .form select {float:left; width:146px; margin-top:10px}
 .form .submit {clear:both}
 .form #confirmMessage {font-size: 0.9em;}
```

I also added a `<br>` after the first `input`. And the result is like [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TesrL/).